# Using an object inside a class in same scala file

Tags: scala, object

The following is the example that I am working on,

```
package com.sandbox.scala


class ScalaOne {

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    com.sandbox.scala.sayHello.hello(); //This works
    sayHello.hello(); //error: not found: value sayHello

  }

}

object sayHello{
    def hello(){
      println("Hello from Scala");
    }
  }
```

As you may see the second call `sayHello.hello()` throws an error mentioned in the comment. Why is that? I assumed it should work.

Comment: I can compile that exact file without problem with Scala 2.11.1. That said, you're playing with fire by having your package containing (and *ending*) with `scala`. Leave it to `com.sandbox` or anything that does not contain `scala`, and it will probably work better. As a side note, the established style guide suggests that top-level objects such as `sayHello` be named with a starting uppercase (hence `SayHello`).

Comment: @sjrd I tried the same code in 2.11.1 with the latest scala IDE, it doesn't seem to work unless I reference it with full package